# Embed a single field from an existing content in ckeditor

Tags: 8

I managed to embed the full content or teaser using Entity Embed module in Drupal 8 but, is it possible to embed a single field which contains text or html without coding

Comment: `Full` and `teaser` are view modes showing different fields. You could create a third view mode (`/admin/structure/display-modes/view`), configure the this node display mode to show only one specific field (`/admin/structure/types/manage/NODE_TYPE/display/VIEW_MODE`) and then embed them as usual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using tokens. The exact token used will vary based on your configuration, but if you wanted to embed a the current user's first name, you could use something like [current-user:field_first_name]. Here's one article about them. https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/tokens-in-drupal-fields/